# iPhone active network type (2G, 3G, WiFi)

Tags: iphone, networking, wifi

Does anyone know how to determine the active network type at the specific moment: *2G*, *3G* or *WiFi*.

For example, at a specific moment there could be enabled *3G*, but the used network type could be *2G*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `SCNetworkReachability` interface can help you with that. Basically, you create a so-called reachability reference and then call `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` on it to get information about the connection.

The returned flags include `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN`, which tells you whether you are connected via WiFi or the cell network. AFAIK it cannot be used to tell the difference between 2G and 3G, though.

See Apple's [Reachability sample app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) for an implementation. In most cases, you should be able to directly use the included `Reachability` class in your project.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Apple Developer site, and download a sample project called "Reachability"

It provides an example of what you would like to do.

It is worth noting that I don't believe that you can tell the difference between EDGE(2G) and a 3G connection. It's either WiFi or WWAN.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the way to find the network mode(2G,3G,4G or wifi) of your device in swift.

```
if let reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection() {

        reachability.startNotifier()

        let status = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()

        if status == .init(0) {
            // .NotReachable

            print("Not Reachable")

        }
        else if status == .init(1) {
            // .ReachableViaWiFi

            print("Reachable Via WiFi")

        }
        else if status == .init(2) {
            // .ReachableViaWWAN
            let netInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

            if let cRAT = netInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology  {

                switch cRAT {

                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x:

                    print("Reachable Via 2G")


                    do{
                        try realm.write {
                            realm.add(ModalDataSaver.singletonClass)
                        }
                    }catch
                    {
                        print("Error in saving data :- \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }


                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB,
                     CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD:

                    print("Reachable Via 3G")

                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE:

                    print("Reachable Via 4G")

                default:

                    fatalError("error")

                }
            }
        }
    }
```