# How to get detailed data on iPad cellular connection

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cellular-network

On ipad, is there any way to get detailed data on the cellular connection?

For example

- Am I connected in HSPA+?
- which 3G frequency am I using?

You know all these things only a nerd would wish to know.

So far I could only put an hand on the private API `SoftwareUpdateServices.framework`

```
NSLog(@"TYPE: %d", [[[NetworkMonitor alloc] init] currentNetworkType]);
```

Will return

```
0: NO DATA
1: WIFI
2: GPRS/EDGE
3: 3G
```

Comment: Have a look over this Question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636990/iphone-active-network-type-2g-3g-wifi

Answer (score 0):

I think this link would help:

[Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

The Reachability sample application demonstrates how to use the SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an iPhone or iPod touch. In particular, it demonstrates how to know when IP can be routed and when traffic will be routed through a Wireless Wide Area Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.